# How do I extract a snippet of data from my PHP forum to show a coder the database structure, please?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export, sample

Might there be an online tutorial somewhere that could help teach me how to extract "a sample of the data or just the structure" from my PhpMyAdmin database, please?    Put another way, a freelance developer  has requested of me the following:

"we would need to see at least a snippet... first few lines of the export to see what format is being used with respect to user information, as those fields would need to be mapped in order to create registrations for each user."

Anyhow I see the export button but I am not sure what to do from there.  I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, open the database, click on Export then Custom. Be sure the chosen format is SQL. The next step depends on which phpMyAdmin version you are using, but in the current version (4.5.3) you would untick Data for all of the tables to keep just the Structure. In previous versions, you have a choice of "Structure", take that. Then click on Go and save the resulting .sql file, which is the one the developer is asking for.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insights.   I look forward to giving your suggested approach a try.   Would the .sql file that you mentioned include registered user information?   I'd like to avoid including that if possible.   At any rate, thanks again Marc.   Happy 2016.   :-)

Comment: If you follow exactly my suggestion, there will be no data at all, just the structure. And you always have the liberty of inspecting yourself the generated .sql file in any text editor, just to be sure.

Comment: As a follow-up, I just tried your approach and voila, it worked and apparently lacks personal user data too.   Thanks so much Marc.   Happy 2016!   :-)

Comment: Happy 2016 and please mark my answer above as the correct one.

Comment: Hi Marc:
    I've repeatedly tried to mark your answer as correct (by clicking on the upward arrow) but the interface says I need 15 points before I can visibly affect your score.   Is there a button that I'm somehow missing though?  Your help's been much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, come back later :) meanwhile can you click on the up arrow to improve the score?

Comment: Hi Marc:
    Perhaps I'm not doing it right because I get the negative response when I try to click the upward arrow.   In fact I'd tried to click it last week.   But you deserve my support so hopefully I can figure out a way.   :-)

Comment: You probably need more reputation points to even be allowed to vote.